# Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources Run bundle install to install missing gems

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux and after I done apt-get dist-upgrade I keep receiving this ''Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources Run bundle install to install missing gems. '' When I do ''bundle install'' I receive this

Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`.

I have made another non-root user and it give me same thing + I have recreated ./bundle and same error after that and tried to reinstall 'rake-11.2.2 ' I can't because I receive same error like above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be on the `metasploit-framework` folder first

```
cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework/
bundle install
```

if you get a error installing `nokogiri-1.6.8` try to:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev --yes
```

and rerun the `bundle install` on the correct folder

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer from here after going around alot and banging my head alot

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539636/bundlergemfilenotfound-whenever-i-try-to-run-bundle-install

*simply run gem install bundler then bundler install as root in the tool root path and everything works as charm.
to go to the tool root path 
cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework*

Answer (score -1):

To fix this I ran `apt-get install ruby-rails*`